# If a series is divergent, then series of magnitude of its terms is also divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

Is it the case that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ diverges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|a_n|}$ also diverges?

It seems obvious that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is unbounded (i.e., $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{S_n}\rightarrow \infty \text{ or }-\infty$) then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|a_n|}$ is also unbounded and the claim follows for this case.

But for other cases, I find it a bit tricky.

Note: $S_n$ denotes $n$th partial sum.

Comment: Either all terms of your series have the same sign, which is the case you've handled, or you can split the series into two subseries: one having all the positive terms and the other having all the negative terms, and then reason about that.  You need to be careful about rearrangements though.

Comment: The case I have handled is that if $S_n\rightarrow \infty$ then the sum of positive terms tends to $\infty$ and thus the sum of magnitude of all the terms tends to $\infty$. Similarly for $S_n\rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: The contrapositive statement is usually proven in every basic real analysis book "absolute convergence implies convergence" (of course we must be dealing with Banach spaces, eg $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$). This is shown by proving that $\{S_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy-sequence: if $n\geq m$ then $|S_n-S_m|=\left|\sum_{j=m+1}^na_j\right|\leq \sum_{j=m+1}^n|a_j|$, and this can be made small provided $m$ is large enough.

Comment: Now I really feel stupid, thanks. But why did you post your answer as comment?